# Bounding an exponential integral by finding a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, asymptotics, exponential-function

I am not sure whether such a function $p(r)$ actually exists. My intuition is choosing an exponential-type function that decreases rapidly for values of $r$ away from
$t$ can potentially ensure that the integral goes to $0$ as $\frac{t}{\sqrt{A}} \rightarrow \infty$. But I couldn't prove this.

One more constraint: $p(r)$ should be independent of $t$.

Comment: As stated your question is not really understandable. You seem to have removed the integral in question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated it is not possible to find such a $p$. To see this, we pick $A=1=w$ and let $t\rightarrow \infty$ (that's all compatible with the assumptions). Then we note that the integrand is positive and hence we have for $t\geq 2$

$$I(t,1)\geq \int_1^2 \frac{t^2}{4} p(r) \exp\left( -\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{2}{r} \right)dr \geq \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4} \right)}{4} \left(\int_1^2 p(r) dr \right) t^2. $$

The integral over $p$ needs to vanish in order to make $I(t,1)=o(1)$, which contradicts the assumption that $p>0$.

Comment: I see, but can we actually give an upper bound to the integral, independent of $t, A$?

Comment: @MathsFreak In my post above I show that the integral diverges to $\infty$ for $t\rightarrow \infty$ (no matter what you choose for $p>0$), so you cannot hope to get an upper bound independent of $t,A$.